# How to capture the results of columns after querying tdbinput (database) into a global variable to use later in talend

Tags: javascript, java, database, global-variables, talend

In the talend job,i would like to extract the values of all the columns from a table and store into each global variables and then use that to perform other operations.

tdbinput1 has the query:

```
"SELECT   a.FILE_NAME,  a.FILE_DATE,a.file_size
--into context.dbfile_name,context.dbfile_size 
FROM FILE a
LEFT JOIN DIR b ON a.DIRID=b.DIRID
LEFT JOIN LOAD c ON a.LOADID=c.LOADID "
```

The row-wise data from the table needs to be inserted into another table after extracting using stored procedure.

My concern here is how to capture all the column values in the query itself ?or the only other way is to use tjavarow and globalmap variables like below:?

tjavarow:

```
globalMap.put("FILE_NAME", input_row.FILE_NAME);
globalMap.put("FILE_DATE", input_row.FILE_DATE);
```

The data-flow looks as such:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osSdf.png)

Comment: Hello, why do you need to save them in globalMap? If you have defined in the schema of tdbinput the column to field mapping, you can then use rowX.field1, rowX.field2 ... from the output row of  tdbinput to extract the DB table's column values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tHashOutput / tHashInput components could be the best suited for you. They allow you to store data in cache and reuse it further in your job. Check in Project Properties/Designer/palette as those components are hidden by default.